# React-Native: Useeffect not updating state after fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to do a GET fetch request to certain endpoint. My problem is that running the app, I get this error message: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 39):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Although after re-saving my visual studio code file, I can see all 16 objects.

```js
 const TotalEarnings = () => {

  const [test, setTest] = useState("")
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getEarnings(){
        const headers = await GetUserToken()
        const response = await fetch('This is where I have my API', 
        {method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'token-type': 'Bearer', ACCEPT: 'application/json',
           
          }).then((res) => res.json())
          .then(result => setData(result.body, 'last promosise data'))
          console.log(data)
          .then(response, 'test response')
        
     
  
        setTest( await AsyncStorage.getItem('access-token'))
        setTest( await AsyncStorage.getItem('client'))
        setTest( await AsyncStorage.getItem('expiry'))
        setTest( await AsyncStorage.getItem('uid'))
         }
         getEarnings()     
   },[] );
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

This is what my console looks when I have run the app once, and after saving the file again, the objects appear in the console...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRXmm.png

Comment: Add a catch method at the end of the then chain to catch the error

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the `then` chain by inserting a `console.log` in between them.

```
  ...
  .then(result => setData(result.body, 'last promosise data'))
  console.log(data)  // This breaks the chain
  .then(response, 'test response') // This causes Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection
  ...
```

`.then(response, 'test response')` causes Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection since console.log does not resolve any promise. Removing it eliminates the promise rejection.

Comment: Hi I tried removing the line with console.log(data) I still get the same result: When running the the arrays with objects is empty. Saving the file again makes the array of objects appear in the console.